# Using MemoryStream to save .docx file C#

Tags: .net, c#-3.0, memorystream, docx

I've some trouble to upload file from Memory Stream to database (it's visible in DB as 0x so i guess it doesn't get saved properly). I am not sure whether it's a problem with Stream being created or save to db from stream should be done differently.

```
private void test {
        byte[] storage = new byte[500000];
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(storage))
        DocX documentWord = DocX.Create(stream);
        // some stuff
        documentWord.Save(); 
        databaseFilePut(stream);
}


public static void databaseFilePut(MemoryStream stream) {
        byte[] file;
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream)) {
                file = reader.ReadBytes((int) stream.Length);
               // reader.Close();
        }
            //stream.Close();
        //}
        using (var varConnection = Locale.sqlConnectOneTime(Locale.sqlDataConnectionDetailsDZP))
        using (var sqlWrite = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Raporty (RaportPlik) Values(@File)", varConnection)) {
            sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarBinary, file.Length).Value = file;
            sqlWrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

What am i doing wrong? I am using Docx codeplex library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're writing to the stream and then immediately trying to read from it *without rewinding*... so there's no data to read.

Fortunately, there's a very easy way of simplifying the code anyway:

```
byte[] file = stream.ToArray();
```

However, you've got another potential problem:

```
byte[] storage = new byte[500000];
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(storage))
...
```

This will make the `MemoryStream` have a *fixed* size of 500K - no more, no less. I suspect that's not what you want; I suggest you get rid of the `storage` variable and just call the parameterless `MemoryStream` constructor.

Comment: Thank you. I knew i was missing something :-)